# Prove $\frac{1}{2} + \cos(x) + \cos(2x) + \dots+ \cos(nx) = \frac{\sin(n+\frac{1}{2})x}{2\sin(\frac{1}{2}x)}$ for $x \neq 0, \pm 2\pi, \pm 4\pi,\dots$

Tags: sequences-and-series, proof-writing, induction

I know that this can be proven inductively. However, I can't get passed the trig. I am pretty sure trig identities can show that the expression above is true for $n=0$, and that if the expression holds for $n=k$ it holds for $n=k+1$. But alas, I am getting lost in a sea of trig. Hopefully someone can shed some light on this.

Comment: Hint : $\sum_{k=1}^n cos(nx)=Re(\sum_{k=1}^n e^{inx})$

Comment: Looks like you can derive this result using Fourier series

Comment: @peterwhy That would be odd, since this is an important inequality to derive some identities concerning the Dirichlet kernel.

Comment: @PedroTamaroff well, not exactly using a lot of Fourier series, but deriving using an idea from frequency domain is possible.

Comment: @peterwhy (I wouldn't say your answer is using Fourier series, but it is a nice one. +1)

Comment: Related : http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/17966/how-can-we-sum-up-sin-and-cos-series-when-the-angles-are-in-arithmetic-pro

Answer (score 6):

Hint:
$$\frac{1}{2} + \sum_{k=1}^n \cos(kx)
= \frac{1}{2}\sum_{k=-n}^n e^{ikx}$$

Answer (score 5):

Hint:
$$
2\cos(kx)\,\sin(\frac{x}{2})=\sin\left(kx+\frac{x}{2}\right)- \sin\left(kx-\frac{x}{2}\right)
$$