# Prove that $\frac{1}{2} + \sum_{k=1}^n\cos(kx) = \frac{\sin(n+\frac{1}{2})x}{2\sin(\frac{1}{2}x)}$ for any $x\in\Bbb R$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, sequences-and-series, solution-verification, induction

So I'd like to prove that for any $x\in\Bbb R$ the formula
$$
\frac{1}{2} + \sum_{k=1}^n\cos(kx) = \frac{\sin\Big((n+\frac{1}{2})x\Big)}{2\sin\frac{x}{2}}
$$
holds.

First of all we observe that the quantity $2\sin\frac x2$ is zero if and only if $x=2h\pi$ for any $h\in\Bbb Z$ so that to prove the formula when $x=2h\pi$ for any $h\in\Bbb Z$ we calculate the limit of the function $\frac{\sin\left(n+\frac{1}{2}\right)x}{2\sin\frac{x}{2}}$ as $x$ approaches $2h\pi$.

> > Previously we remember that if $k$ is even, then
> > $$
> > \sin x=\sin(x-k\pi)
> > $$
> > for any $x\in\Bbb R$ whereas if $k$ is odd then
> > $$
> > \sin x=-\sin(x-k\pi)
> > $$
> > for any $x\in\Bbb R$; moreover we remember that the product of two odd number is odd whereas the product of an odd number with a even number is even so that if $h\in\Bbb Z$ is odd then the number $(2n+1)h$ is odd whereas it is even when $h$ is even. So if $h\in\Bbb Z$ is even it follows that
> > $$
> > \sin\biggl(\Big(n+\frac 12\Big)x\biggl)=\sin\biggl(\big(2n+1\big)\frac x2\biggl)=
> > \sin\biggl(\big(2n+1\big)\frac x 2-\big(2n+1\big)h\pi\biggl)\,\text{and}\,\sin\frac x2=\sin\biggl(\frac x 2-h\pi\biggl)
> > $$
> > for any $x\in\Bbb R$ whereas if $h$ is odd then it follows that
> > $$
> > \sin\biggl(\Big(n+\frac 12\Big)x\biggl)=\sin\biggl(\big(2n+1\big)\frac x2\biggl)=-\sin\biggl(\big(2n+1\big)\frac x 2-\big(2n+1\big)h\pi\biggl)\,\text{and}\,\sin\frac x2=-\sin\biggl(\frac x 2-h\pi\biggl)
> > $$
> >
> > for any $x\in\Bbb R$.
> >
> > So we conclude that
> > $$
> > \lim_{x\rightarrow 2h\pi} \frac{\sin\Big((n+\frac{1}{2})x\Big)}{2\sin\frac{x}{2}}=\\
> > \lim_{x\rightarrow 2h\pi} \frac{\sin\Big((2n+1)\frac x2\Big)}{2\sin\frac{x}{2}}=\\
> > \lim_{x\rightarrow 2h\pi} \frac{\sin\Big((2n+1)\frac x2-(2n+1)h\pi\Big)}{2\sin\Big(\frac{x}{2}-h\pi\Big)}=\\
> > \lim_{x\rightarrow 2h\pi} \frac 1 2\cdot\frac{\sin\biggl((2n+1)\Big(\frac x2-h\pi\Big)\biggl)}{(2n+1)\Big(\frac x 2-h\pi\Big)}\cdot\frac{\frac x 2-h\pi}{\sin\Big(\frac x2-h\pi\Big)}\cdot(2n+1)=\\
> > \frac 1 2\cdot(2n+1)=n+\frac 1 2
> > $$
> >
> > Now we remember that if $m\in\Bbb Z$ is an even number then
> > $$
> > \cos(m\pi)=1
> > $$
> > so that finally
> > $$
> > \lim_{x\rightarrow 2h\pi} \frac{\sin\Big((n+\frac{1}{2})x\Big)}{2\sin\frac{x}{2}}=\frac 12 +n=\frac 12+\sum_{k=1}^n\cos\big(k(2h\pi)\big)
> > $$
> > and this proves that the formula effectively holds when $x=2h\pi$ for any $h\in\Bbb Z$, **provided that the argumentations I gave are correct**.

So now we have to prove the formula when $x\neq2h\pi$ for any $h\in\Bbb Z$.

> > First of all we remember that the [$4$-th prosthaphaeresis formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prosthaphaeresis) guarantees that
> > $$
> > \sin\alpha-\sin\beta=2\sin\frac{\alpha-\beta}2\cos\frac{\alpha+\beta}2
> > $$
> > for any $\alpha,\beta\in\Bbb R$ so that we can conclude that
> > $$
> > \sin\biggl(\Big(k+\frac 12\Big)x\biggl)-\sin\biggl(\Big(k-\frac 12\Big)x\biggl)=\\
> > \sin\Big(\frac{2kx+x}x\Big)-\sin\Big(\frac{2kx-x}2\Big)=\\
> > 2\sin\Biggl(\frac{\frac{2kx+x}2-\frac{2kx-x}2}2\Biggl)\cos\Biggl(\frac{\frac{2kx+x}2+\frac{2kx-x}2}2\Biggl)=\\
> > 2\sin\Biggl(\frac{(2kx+x)-(2kx-x)}4\Biggl)\cos\Biggl(\frac{(2kx+x)+(2kx-x)}4\Biggl)=\\
> > 2\sin\frac x 2\cos kx
> > $$
> >
> > for any $x\in\Bbb R$. So using this result I tried to prove the statement by induction. So let's prove the formula for $k=1$.

> > So for $k=1$ the above identity implies that
> > $$
> > \sin\biggl(\big(1+\frac 12\big)x\biggl)-\sin\frac x 2=\\
> > \sin\biggl(\Big(1+\frac 12\Big)\biggl)-\sin\biggl(\Big(1-\frac 1 2\Big)x\biggl)=2\sin\frac x 2\cos x
> > $$
> > so that it follows that
> > $$
> > \frac{\sin\biggl(\Big(1+\frac12\Big)x\biggl)}{2\sin\frac x2}-\frac 12=
> > \cos x\Rightarrow\frac 12+\cos x=
> > \frac{\sin\biggl(\Big(1+\frac12\Big)x\biggl)}{2\sin\frac x2}
> > $$
> > since $x\neq2h\pi$ for any $h\in\Bbb Z$.

> > So we assume that the formula holds for an arbitrary $n$ and thus we want to prove that it holds for $(n+1)$.

Well unfortuantely I am not able to show that the formula holds for $(n+1)$ when it holds for $n$ so I thought to post an another question where I ask to do it; Here I ask if the argumentations I gave for the case $x=2h\pi$ are correct. So could someone help me, please?

Comment: I have seen similar, if not the same, questions on this site many times. Have looked at any of them?

Comment: Various solutions here: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/17966/42969

Comment: @Bumblebee Reserching on Google I only found [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/520719/prove-frac12-cosx-cos2x-dots-cosnx-frac-sinn-frac1) but it does not help. Anyway I see MartinR put another link now.

Comment: @MartinR Sorry but the question you linked seems different from mine: what can you say about?

Comment: You don't need induction. The formula turns it into a telescoping sum with only the first and last terms left.

Comment: @martycohen Okay, so could you show that the formula can be write as a telescoping sum, please?

Comment: There is a very simple proof using complex numbers. Are you familiar with that?

Comment: @DavidQuinn I know Euler formula; anyway I like the martycohen solution.

Comment: also you can see the second linked item on the right of this page

Comment: @DavidQuinn I already saw it but unfortunately the answer was not very clear, sorry.

Comment: @DavidQuinn Well, I know that $\cos kx=\frac{e^{ikx}+e^{-ikx}}2$ so that $\sum_{k=1}^n\cos kx=\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{e^{ikx}+e^{-ikx}}2$ but I do not understand how transform this last identity into the peterwhy's identity. Forgive my confusion.

Comment: It's not the most obvious way to set about it IMHO. I thought you were more interested in the telescoping series method?

Comment: @DavidQuinn sorry but I do not really understand what you want mean with your first sentence. Anyway I am sure more interested about the telescoping solution, you say right.

Comment: I mean I don't think you need to use the hint your refer to

Comment: @DavidQuinn Ah, okay: anyway I repeat you I tried to use complex numebr but unfortunately this was unsucessfull. In any case could you help me, please?

Comment: Note that the right hand side is not **defined** when $x=2k\pi$

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen Oh yeah! This is sure: indeed this is really the reason for which I calculate the limit as $x$ approaches at $2k\pi$ for any $k\in\Bbb Z$ so that we can say that the formula holds for "*continuity extension*", right?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Consider, when $x\neq m.2\pi, m\in\mathbb{Z}$, $$\sum_{k=1}^{n}e^{ikx}=\frac{e^{ix}(e^{inx}-1)}{e^{ix}-1}$$(being the sum of a geometric series whose ratio is $\neq 1$)
$$=\frac{e^{i\frac12x}e^{inx}-e^{i\frac12x}}{e^{i\frac12x}-e^{-i\frac12x}}$$
$$=\frac{e^{ix(n+\frac12)}-e^{i\frac12x}}{2i\sin\frac x2}$$

Considering the real part of both sides,
$$\sum_{k=1}^{n}\cos(kx)=\frac{\sin(n+\frac12)x-\sin(\frac x2)}{2\sin(\frac x2)},$$
and the result follows immediately.

For $x=m.2\pi$, the proof follows the same lines as you have already done.

Comment: Okay, so  **only** I understood that $$\frac{e^{i\frac12x}e^{inx}-e^{i\frac12x}}{e^{i\frac12x}-e^{-i\frac12x}}
=\frac{e^{ix(n+\frac12)}-e^{i\frac12x}}{2i\sin\frac x2}$$ but all the rest is unfortunately unclear. Forgive me if I am stranger with complex numbers.

Comment: If you are unclear with complex numbers then try induction. It is your best hope. (But complex analysis is simpler if you have that available to you.)

Comment: @ShannonStarr Unfortunately induction seems much complicated but as you can see by your self pheraps I found another solution: what do you think about my answer?

Comment: @DavidQuinn Okay, now it is clear: question upvoted and approved. Moreover could I ask if my answer about "telescopic" method is correct? Anyway thanks very much for your assistance!!!

Answer (score 1):

As Marty Cohen suggest in the comment above the result follows immediately showing that the serie
$$
\sum_{k=1}^\infty\cos(kx)
$$
is [telescopic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Telescoping_series). So by the [4-th prosthaphaeresis formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prosthaphaeresis) we know that
$$
\sin\biggl(\Big(k+\frac 12\Big)x\biggl)-\sin\biggl(\Big(k-\frac 12\Big)x\biggl)=
2\sin\frac x 2\cos kx
$$
and thus observing that
$$
\sin\biggl(\Big(k+\frac 12\Big)x\biggl)-\sin\biggl(\Big(k-\frac 12\Big)x\biggl)=\sin\biggl(\Big((k+1)-\frac 12\Big)x\biggl)-\sin\biggl(\Big(k-\frac 12\Big)x\biggl)
$$
the result follows immediately.

Comment: How is that different from https://math.stackexchange.com/a/520725/42969?

Comment: @MartinR Is there mentioned telescopic serie? Moreover is there debated the case where $x=2h\pi$ for any $h\in\Bbb Z$?